# ContextMenu is not binding for datagrid WPF

Tags: wpf

> I have a datagrid which is binded to a viewmodel, On the datagrid i have a contextmenu i am trying to make a command behaviour which is not working.

```
<DataGrid Margin="5,0,0,0">
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
       <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
         <Setter.Value>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Column1"></MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="Column2" Command="{Binding ShowEditColumnWindow}"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
      </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
```

Comment: **Perhaps**, my code here could help you a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585518/wpf-canexecute-doesnt-work-for-datagrids-contextmenu/

Answer (score 0):

try with this code, add Path

```
   <MenuItem Header="Column2" Command="{Binding Path=ShowEditColumnWindow}"/>
```