# WPF - CanExecute doesn't work for DataGrid's ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, command

I wanted to have my DataGrids with a context menu that allows the user to move the selected rows up or down. After some search, I've come up with the following code that has a problem. It seems that `CanExecute` is only called once (I guess when the menu gets created), so my MenuItem will either be enabled or disabled **all of the time**. What I am struggling to achieve is to make it enabled when there are rows selected in the DataGrid and disabled when there aren't any. Currently this doesn't work.

Also, is there a more elegant solution to this? If I use more code I think it will become a huge mess...

```
public class DataGridMoveRowsUpCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        var grid = parameter as DataGrid;
        if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count > 0) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // Do sth...
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null) CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{
    public static ICommand DataGridMoveRowsUp
    {
        get { return new DataGridMoveRowsUpCommand(); }
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
        <kbm:MyDataGrid x:Name="gridExpenses" ContextMenu="{StaticResource DataGridContextMenu}"/>

//-------------------------------------------------------------
        <ContextMenu x:Key="DataGridContextMenu" x:Shared="true">
            <MenuItem Header="{DynamicResource StringMoveUp}"
                     Command="kbm:MyDataGrid.DataGridMoveRowsUp"
                     CommandTarget="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
            </MenuItem>
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to manually called `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method whenever you feel like that command needs to be revaluated. (Most probably in case `SelectedItems` of dataGrid gets changed.)

OR

Either you can let `CommandManager` decides when to raise `CanExecuteChanged` event of your command by hooking onto `RequerySuggested` event of CommandManager like this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

> `RequerySuggested` event Occurs when the
>   System.Windows.Input.CommandManager detects conditions that might
>   change the ability of a command to execute.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By using your 2nd suggestion I managed to make it work! I am not sure how `CommandManager` understands when it needs to re-evaluate the `CanExecute()` but that's another issue! :)